# opening a tab delimitted file using linux commands

Tags: excel, sed, awk, grep, delimiter

I'm having a very difficult time opening a tab delimitted file. The client says that it is definitely tab delimitted, but it seems like there are no text qualifiers.

I am running this statement:

```
 awk '{OF=OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2,$10,$12,$14,$20}' AECPRDA.TAB | head -10
```

and the output that i get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 22746528        BKEN48DVD       NEVER   050     R       N             |
| 22746535        BKEN48BR        NEVER   050     R       N             |
| 25584998        WD1194190DVD    DTS)    /       DOL     29.99         |
| 21548598        DSND001906102.2 /       001     11.49   8             |
| 25812794        WHV1000292717BR /       050     PG13    N             |
| 25812787        WHV1000284958DVD        SPEC    GRAVITY /       PG13  |
| 21425462        PBSDMST64400DVD SEASON  (3PC)   CLASSIC:        050   |
| 25584974        WD1194170BR     (WS     DTS     DIGC)   AC3           |
| 21388262        HBO1000394029DVD        3       OF      SEASON  59.98 |
| 25688450        WD11955700DVD   /       DOL)    THE     050           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't believe that the columns are correctly "tabbed":

[image]

here's is a PURE text sample of the file:

```
22746528    BKEN48DVD   AW40    48  18  METALLICA (2PC) THROUGH THE NEVER (2PC) 050 090     R   12.99   19.98   85611500487 01/28/2014          N   N   30      1   A   1   11/27/2013  01/24/2014  11/27/2013  11/27/2013
22746535    BKEN48BR    AW40    48  BR  METALLICA (2PC) THROUGH THE NEVER (2PC) 050 090     R   16.25   24.98   85611500488 01/28/2014          N   N   30      1   A   2   11/27/2013  01/24/2014  11/27/2013  11/27/2013
25584998    WD1194190DVD    0819    1194190 18  FROZEN / (WS DOL DTS)   FROZEN / (WS DOL DTS)   050 110     G   21.25   29.99   78693683896 03/18/2014          N   N   0       2   A   3   12/20/2013  03/20/2014  12/20/2013  12/20/2013
21548598    DSND001906102.2 0107    001906102   02  FROZEN / O.S.T. FROZEN / O.S.T. 001 024         11.49   13.95   05008729574 11/25/2013          N   N   8       1   E   4   10/07/2013  03/20/2014  10/07/2013  10/07/2013
25812794    WHV1000292717BR 0526    1000292717  BR  GRAVITY / (UVDC)    GRAVITY / (UVDC)    050 093     PG13    29.49   35.99   88392924457 02/25/2014          N   N   30      1   E   5   01/16/2014  02/11/2014  01/16/2014  01/16/2014
```

**am i doing something wrong with my AWK commands? why aren't the tabs being set correctly? is there a hidden "space" qualifier that i am missing?**

here is an explanation that i got from someone, but i would like to implement it using AWK NOT excel (gd forbid):
[image]

> Tab delimited will probably not line up.  The tab character is defined
>   differently in different operating systems.  Usually it is defined as
>   4 or 5 spaces when displayed.  So if you have an artist name that is 5
>   characters, then the tab characher, then the title would start at
>   character position 9.  If the next line the artist is 20 characters
>   long, then the tab character, then the title would appear at position
>   24. Hope this helps. (Another thought, tell user to open a blank spreadsheet in excel and use the Text Import)

thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: I don't really understand the `{OF=OFS="\t"}` part. Shouldn't it be `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` to set the Input and Output Field Separators as tab?

Comment: It you "don't believe that the columns are correctly tabbed" then it isn't really a tab-delimited file and you'll need to understand what your input format actually is and if it can be formalized (possibly with a regular expression).

Comment: please see my update, i think it should be more clear now but i don tkonw how to implement it

Comment: If you're not convinced, try counting the number of fields on each line: `awk -F '\t' '{print NF}' filename`

Comment: this is such a huge pain, excel opens this without a problem, but awk does not, i dont understand

Comment: guys check out my answer! do you know why this different type of tab works??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!

Instead of using this kind of tab character: `"\t"`

I needed to use `$'\t'`

I haven't found documentation on why, though.

Final answer:

```
awk -F$'\t' 'BEGIN{OF=OFS}{print $1,$2,$10,$12,$14,$20}' AECPRDA.TAB | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR<=10 {print $1,$2,$10,$12,$14,$20}' AECPRDA.TAB
```

Comment: please see my update, i think it should be more clear now but i don tkonw how to implement it

Comment: You do not need the `head -10`, its replaced by `NR<=10`.

Comment: The pure text in your first post, is that the data you are using?  I do not get the same result with it as you do.

Comment: what result do you get? the funny thing is when i import it into excel as tab delimitted, everything works fine: http://screencast.com/t/PmWxitMrGyiL

Comment: try running `dos2unix` on your input file first to make sure you don't have extraneous control-Ms at the end of each line, e.g. if your file was created on Windows.